# the google api to get the list of websites for given adwords

Tags: c#, adsense, google-ads-api

i am developing a desktop application using c#.net

where i need to get the list of all websites that are using google adsense for the given list of keywords

for that what Google api i need to use.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no straight forward way you can get this information from Google.

If you already running Adwords on those keywords, you can export the keyword reports and parse them in you app (MS Excel is a better tool here).